# Automatically scroll to the top of a TextView control in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a TextView control in my ViewController with a whole bunch of text in it. Too much to display at once.

When the controller loads the text that show is about in the middle of the  complete text. I can scroll to the top or the bottom manually ok, but *I want the text to be at the start of the whole text when the controller loads.*

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `contentOffset` of your `textView` to programmatically scroll to the top:

```
textView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
```

Do it in your `viewDidLayoutSubviews` function, which is:

> Called to notify the view controller that its view has just laid out
>   its subviews.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    textView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: false)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great.